# Django-medusa can't render wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I want render my wagtail site to static site using django-medusa like this documentation http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.1/reference/contrib/staticsitegen.html . In this step ./manage.py staticsitegen I get an error like this :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/home/ifanramza/Desktop/CMS/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
      File "/home/ifanramza/Desktop/CMS/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/home/ifanramza/Desktop/CMS/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 195, in fetch_command
klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
      File "/home/ifanramza/Desktop/CMS/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 39, in load_command_class
module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
      File "/home/ifanramza/Desktop/CMS/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_medusa/management/commands/staticsitegen.py", line 2, in <module>
from django_medusa.renderers import StaticSiteRenderer
      File "/home/ifanramza/Desktop/CMS/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_medusa/renderers/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.utils import importlib
    ImportError: cannot import name importlib
```

But i have importlib module in installed apps. Is something wrong with my configuration? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See the latest Wagtail docs - http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/staticsitegen.html?highlight=medusa

> django-medusa is no longer maintained, and is incompatible with Django 1.8 and above; the information below is retained for historical reference only. An alternative module based on the django-bakery package is available as a third-party contribution: https://github.com/mhnbcu/wagtailbakery